# How does d3.js(version:3) figure out it is a radial tree layout

Tags: d3.js

everyone! I am trying to learn d3 layout, and I get two questions inroad.

Just as the documents [tree.size([size])](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Tree-Layout.md#size) mentioned, size is a two-element array. Say I set one tree like this:

```
d3.layout.tree().size([360, Radius])
```

Now there seems to have two situations: a normal tree layout OR a radial tree layout that with *360* in degree and *Radius* in depth.

**Question 1:**

How does d3 interpret a array which may represent a normal tree or a radial tree?

**Question 2:**

I find that d3.layout.cluster is very close to tree layout. Is anybody can tell me what is the difference?
This question maybe a little foolish.

Any suggestion will be appreciated! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For either d3v3 or d3v4, the size array can be used for a normal or a radial tree. These will always return x,y values for each node of a normal tree, we would have to force those coordinates into a radial alignment to get a radial tree:

> The layout size is specified in x and y, but this is not limited
>   screen coordinates and may represent an arbitrary coordinate system. ([v3 documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Tree-Layout.md)).

If we look at this [block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550) by Mike Bostock (v4), we can see that a special projection function is called to create a radial effect:

```
  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
    .data(root.descendants())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + project(d.x, d.y) + ")"; });
```

And that the projection function looks like:

```
function project(x, y) {
  var angle = (x - 90) / 180 * Math.PI, radius = y;
  return [radius * Math.cos(angle), radius * Math.sin(angle)];
}
```

Overall this gives a shape like:

[image]

The projection function is the only thing that makes it radial. If we change the projection function to just pass through x,y data:

```
function project(x, y) {
  return [x,y];
}
```

we get a typical tree layout. However, the g element everything is appended to is translated to the center, and the width,height don't match the svg. If we were to set these properly (translation of [0,0] and width and height of tree to match svg, we would get this:

[image]

*Note that the labels are still rotated as there is still an inline function setting their arrangement.*

---

As for the difference between cluster and tree, the API [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#cluster) does provide some help:

> The cluster layout produces dendrograms: node-link diagrams that place
>   leaf nodes of the tree at the same depth.

If you note in the tree diagram in the radial example, not all leaves are at the same depth, the circle does not have an even radius. Take a look at this [block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339607) for a comparison (also from Mike Bostock, and in captured in the image below):

[image]